# Unable to set default input radio checked if used with v-for

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to add radio buttons to my code. Everything works fine except one thing. When I am using v-for loop for creating radios, the default radio is not getting checked. It works if, I put it outside the for loop.

I have tried this :-

> :checked="index == 1"

and this ( as suggested in some answers ):-

> :checked="{ index == 1 }"

But none of them is working for me.

Below is my template snippet:-

```
<div class="props-data">
  <!-- <input type="radio" :checked="currentStep==1"> -->
  <span v-for="(shape, index) in availableShapes" v-if="currentStep==1">
    <div>
      <input type="radio" :id="shape" :value="shape" v-model="selectedShape" :checked="index == 1">
      <label :for="shape">{{shape}}</label>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
```

Note:- **steps-container** is the main parent class where Vue instance is being created.

Below is my js code:-

```
window.onload = function(){
new Vue({
    el: '#steps-container',
    data: function() {
        return {
            currentStep: 1,
            availableShapes: ['Rectangle','Circle','Square','Ellipse'],
            selectedShape: undefined
        };
    },
    methods: {
        cancel: function(){
            this.currentStep = 1;
            jQuery('#main-action').text('Go to step '+ (this.currentStep+1));
        },
        nextStep: function(){
            if( this.currentStep == 2 ){
                jQuery('#main-action').text('Startover');
                this.currentStep++;
            }
            else{
                if( this.currentStep == 3 ){
                    this.currentStep = 1;
                }
                else{
                    this.currentStep++;
                }
                jQuery('#main-action').text('Go to step '+ (this.currentStep+1));
            }
        }
    },
    mounted: function(){
    },
    updated: function(){

    }
});
```

}

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @uzaif no its not working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't need to set the `checked` attr yourself. By using `v-model="selectedShape"` you have linked all the radio input with `selectedShape`.

You can already control the checked attr by controlling the value of `selectedShape`.

So set the initial value of `selectedShape` to the default value, and it will be checked by default.

`<input type="radio" :id="shape" :value="shape" v-model="selectedShape">` (remove `:checked="index == 1"`)

```js
    data: function() {
        return {
            //...
            selectedShape: "THE DEFAULT VALUE"
        };
    },
```

Comment: well.. Vue itself is a charm

Comment: ya thats true...but sometimes i get stuck in the documentation...lol